# Hammer of Purphoros doesn't let me destroy my opponent's lands; why is that exactly?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The text on Hammer of Purphoros reads:

> Sacrifice a land: Put a 3/3 colorless Golem enchantment artifact creature token onto the battlefield.

I know that this doesn't allow me to destroy my opponent's lands but I would like to know why. What wording *would* allow me to do that? "Destroy target land"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Sacrifice" and "Destroy" are 2 separate things, though they both result in sending a permanent to the graveyard. You can only ever sacrifice a permanent that you control:

> 701.14. Sacrifice
>
> > 701.14a To sacrifice a permanent, **its controller** moves it from the battlefield directly to its owner’s graveyard. A player can’t sacrifice something that isn’t a permanent, or something that’s a permanent he or she doesn’t control. Sacrificing a permanent doesn’t destroy it, so regeneration or other effects that replace destruction can’t affect this action.

And you are correct about the second part, a card like [Pillage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pillage) would let you destroy an opponent's land.

"Sacrifice" happens only when an ability tells you to "sacrifice" something (or keywords whose rules require sacrificing, such as Annihilate). "Destruction" can happen either from abilities that say "destroy", or from state-based effects such as a creature having taken too much damage. Things like "Indestructible" can prevent Destruction, but not Sacrificing.

Comment: it might be worth adding a note about destruction being a state based action and clarifying that "indestructible" as an example has no bearing on sacrificing. Just incase anyone gets the idea that a Darksteel Citadel would give them unlimited golems

Comment: @Patters, Destroy is not a SBA. Destroy has noting to do with SBAs (except that some SBAs instruct you to destroy things, just like some SBAs instruct you to remove counters). Destroy is a keyword action (just like "sacrifice", "move", "cast" and "draw"). You are to perform keyword actions when instructed. Just like "sacrifice", "destroy" is simply a wrapper around "move". Having a separate word allows one of the actions to be replaced (e.g. by regeneration) or prevented (e.g. by indestructibility) without affecting the others.

Comment: you are correct, i conflated the destruction that occurs when a creature has lethal damage marked on it (the state based action) with destruction as a whole occurring as a state based action. I still feel the answer could benefit from this clarification of the distinction between sacrifice and destroy though, as the asker (and hence others) appears to not have enough experience to identify the distinction

Comment: @Patters, Rather, I think it's worth mentioning that while Hammer uses "Sacrifice..." as part of a cost, "Destroy target..." _cannot_ be part of a cost. Costs cannot target.

Comment: Is there a rule that says that costs cannot target? I haven't seen that, though it makes sense.

Comment: @GendoIkari, I don't think anything in the rules directly or indirectly forbids targeting in costs, but it would be really weird. 1) There's no chance to response, so there would be no reason to target instead of choosing. 2) Targets are rechecked on resolution, which would make "destroy target {permanent}" particularly problematic.

Comment: @GendoIkari, You'd be far more like to see "As an additional cost, destroy a land", but that you wouldn't see that either. 1) One usually gets a check to response to something destroys (e.g. to put a regeneration shield on the permanent). 2) You could destroy a land with a regeneration shield to pay the cost. 3) A permanent is considered destroyed even if it regenerates, so "Destroy {permanent}. If you do, ..." would not be sufficient to get around the problem described in (2).

Comment: @Brian S, You won't see "Destroy a ..." as part of a cost either. See the previous comment. I did mention that in my answer, and I just fleshed out that part of the answer.

Comment: @GendoIkari, The MtG rules are permissive in nature, not restrictive. That is, they say what you _can_ do (and you can't do anything else), rather than saying what you _can't_ do (while allowing you to do anything else). The CR lists spells, activated abilities, and triggered abilities as possible things with targets. Costs are neither spells, activated abilities, nor triggered abilities, therefore they cannot target. A cost _could_ destroy a permanent in theory (with wording along the lines of "destroy a..." or "choose a..."), but it would not target that permanent.

Comment: @ikegami, You're right, it's extremely unlikely we'll ever see a cost such as "Destroy a..." However, the rules permit such a construction. The rules do _not_ (currently) permit a cost in the form of "Destroy target..."

Comment: Note: there are a small handful of exceptions to the permissive vs. restrictive setup of the rules. For example, 408.1 "[objects in the Command zone] cannot be destroyed"

Comment: @Brian S, I agree that "target" WON'T be found in costs, but you keep saying it CAN'T. I'm not sure it's correct. Could you point out which rule forbids targets in costs?

Comment: @ikegami, As I said, the rules are permissive, not restrictive. There is no rule that says you can't have targets in costs, because there doesn't need to be. The rules only allow for targets in spells, activated abilities, and triggered abilities. Since the rules don't allow for targets anywhere else, you can't have targets in costs.

Comment: @Brian S, An activated ability has the form "cost: effect". If they can't be in *cost* because cost is not one of spells, activated abilities or triggered abilities, then they can't be in *effect* either. And we both know that's not true.

Comment: @ikegami, I disagree. "cost: effect" is the rules text for an activated ability (which might include the word "target"). However, _the activated ability_ is the object which is put onto the stack, which is what actually _has_ a target (if any). The cost of that ability is _not_ on the stack.

Comment: @Brian S, The cost is just as much on the stack as the effect. Which is not at all. Only the ability is on the stack. The ability has *rules text*, which includes a cost and an effect. Anything you say that applies to one applies to the other too.

Comment: I still disagree with your interpretation. I realize this is argument from authority, but: [MTGS Global Mod/Rules Guru Kahedron](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/magic-rulings-archives/301929-psuedo-targeting-for-phantasmal-illusions?comment=2), [MTGS Rules Guru viperesque](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/magic-rulings-archives/311817-illusionists-bracers-deathrite-shaman#c2), [Rules Adviser cyphern](http://community.wizards.com/comment/37467921#comment-37467921)

Comment: Oh, and [L1 Judge ryzorz](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/creativity/custom-card-creation/478911-some-odd-mythics?comment=3). I think that's all for "costs cannot target" and "costs can't target" coming from people in a position of any kind of rules authority. (There were other results for those two searches, but the posters didn't have anything identifying them as having a position of authority of any kind.)

Comment: @Brian S, What interpretation do you disagree with? The rules are explicit about what can go on the stack, and *effect* is not one of them. *Effect* is not even an *object*!!! Look for yourself. You said it's not allowed if it's not in the rules, so tell me where you see that *effects* can be placed on the stack. All you'll find is that *abilities* can, and that *abilities* (as *objects*) have *rules text*.

Comment: @Brian S, I don't the impression that ryzorz was saying the rules prevent it. He's talking about templating, and he's saying you can't write an ability with a cost that targets. I fully agree with that.

Comment: I think it's meaningless to debate whether there is or should be an explicit justification in the rules that "target" cannot occur in a cost, because the rules are not meant to govern what can be printed on cards. The rules are to determine how cards are played.

Comment: @David Z, Templating is actually a widely discussed topic. Thousands would disagree with you. The OP's very question is about it. He's asking "what wording would be used to ...". Saying that "Destroy target land" can't/won't be find on cards is very very relevant to the OP's question; it's the very question at hand!

Comment: Note that protection DOESN'T prevent destruction. It only prevents damage (and attachment, and blocking and targeting). You can have all protections you want, you'll still die to a Wrath of God :)

Answer (score 1):

> What wording would allow me to do that?

*Move {some land} to {a zone}*<sup>[1]</sup>*.*

Other than abilities, some keyword actions instruct you to do this, which brings us to your next question.

> "Destroy target land"?

Yes, because *destroy* is defined as *move {permanent} from the battlefield to its owner’s graveyard*.

You'll never see "target" in a cost, though. There would be problems with doing that, and there would be no gain over simply choosing (e.g. "destroy a land").

That said, you'll never see "destroy" in a cost either. A cost is something you must pay; it should not be a benefit under normal circumstances. Furthermore, destruction can be nullified by regeneration. It should not be possible to avoid paying a cost in that fashion.

> I know that [Sacrifice a land] doesn't allow me to destroy my opponent's lands

Sacrifice is defined as *move {a permanent} you control from the battlefield to its owner’s graveyard*. It would work if it wasn't limited to a permanent you control.

---

1. Note that "return" is sometimes used as a synonym for "move".